# Android resource linking failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

I need to generate app bundle, but the error say :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\fajri\AndroidStudioProjects\Assessment\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:36: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.si20b.assessment:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
     C:\Users\fajri\AndroidStudioProjects\Assessment\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:36: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.si20b.assessment:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.
```

i already put my icon in my android project

Comment: Have checked whether mipmap/ic_launcher is there?

Answer (score 1):

when you create your image assets make sure you choose main mode.

[image]